# Map vectors into integers in a bijective way

Tags: r, function, dictionary, hash

I have 100,000 5-length vectors (the list VECTORS below) whose elements are chosen among one million values.

```
# dictionary
dictionary=seq(1:1e6)

# generate 100,000 5-length vectors whose elements are chosen from dictionary
VECTORS <- lapply(c(1:1e5), sample, x = dictionary, size =5)
```

My problem is to map each exact same vector into one integer, i.e. I need a mappy function that inputs a vector and yields an integer.
`mappy(c(58431, 976854, 661294, 460685, 341123))=15`, for example. Do you know how to do this in an efficient way?

Subsidiary question : what if my vectors aren't the same length anymore?

Comment: There are not enough integers to map `1e6^5` possible vectors.

Comment: It seems that, also, something like `match(VECTORS, unique(VECTORS))` could, perhaps, be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume here you want a bijection between the vectors you have in your list and integers. One approach would be to create a factor variable out of character representations of your vectors. Let's start with a reproducible version of your code (I'll make it a smaller vector):

```
set.seed(144)
VECTORS <- replicate(1e2, sample(seq_len(1e6), 5), FALSE)
```

Now you can create a factor variable from the character representation of each vector:

```
fvar <- factor(sapply(VECTORS, paste, collapse=" "))
```

Now we have a bijection between string representations of elements of `VECTORS` and integers:

```
vec <- c(894025, 153892, 98596, 218401, 36616)  # 15th element of VECTORS
which(levels(fvar) == paste(vec, collapse=" "))
# [1] 90
levels(fvar)[90]
# [1] "894025 153892 98596 218401 36616"
as.numeric(strsplit(levels(fvar)[90], " ")[[1]])
# [1] 894025 153892  98596 218401  36616
```

If you wanted to wrap them up into nice functions:

```
id.from.vec <- function(vec) which(levels(fvar) == paste(vec, collapse=" "))
id.from.vec(c(894025, 153892, 98596, 218401, 36616))
# [1] 90

vec.from.id <- function(id) as.numeric(strsplit(levels(fvar)[id], " ")[[1]])
vec.from.id(90)
# [1] 894025 153892  98596 218401  36616
```

Note that this works out of the box even if the vectors are different lengths.

Answer (score 6):

A keyed data.table has nice lookup properties:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
VECTORS <- lapply(seq(1e5), sample, x = 1e6, size = 5)
VECmap  <- setkey(rbindlist(lapply(unique(VECTORS), as.list)))[, ID := .I]

#             V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     ID
#      1:     13 897309 366563 678873   6571      1
#      2:     15 557977 640484 732531 848939      2
#      3:     48  18120 911805 188728 805726      3
#      4:     48 830301 862433 506297 877432      4
#      5:     52 873436 824165  86251 576173      5
#     ---                                          
#  99996: 999911 583599 803402 240910 931996  99996
#  99997: 999931 146505 287431 180259 230904  99997
#  99998: 999937 175888 266336 874987 982951  99998
#  99999: 999950 960139 455084 586956 875504  99999
# 100000: 999993 191750 258982 518519  78087 100000

mapVEC  <- function(...) VECmap[.(...)]$ID
mapID   <- function(id) unlist(VECmap[ID==id,!"ID",with=FALSE], use.names=FALSE)

# example usage
mapVEC(52, 873436, 824165, 86251, 576173)
# 5
mapID(5)
# 52 873436 824165  86251 576173
```

**Comments** As mentioned by @Roland, a bijection between (a) 1..1e6 and (b) *all* 5-length sequences of distinct numbers from 1..1e5 is not possible, so I'm just guessing that this is what the OP is after.

When you write a function with `...` as an argument, that means an arbitrary number of unnamed arguments are accepted. Within the function, these arguments can be referred to with `...`, but are often also seen with `c(...)` and `list(...)`. Within a data.table, `.(...)` is an alias for `list(...)`. To see documentation for writing functions, type `help.start()` and click through to the "R Language Definition."